# How can I access the code of my deployed Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I have deployed a Shiny app about a 5 years ago. There is a small glitch and I would
like to fix it. How can I access the code of the deployed Shiny application?

Ganesh

Comment: If you deployed it to shinyapps.io, can't you just log in and edit the source?

Comment: How? I have access to the dashboard, but I don't see the source.

Comment: The only way I have found is to fix it locally and deploy it again. I have not seen anything resembling a code editor in my application dashboard.

Comment: I don't have the code which I used to deploy.